# Code to take images from specific drawable folder

Tags: android, android-drawable

How can I code the app such that if the device is 7inch tablet it should take images from drawable-xhdpi? I could of course create folder drawable-sw600dp-hdpi and put my xhdpi images there but the app limit is 50MB, so I need to figure it out.

Comment: doesnt a 7 inch tablet pull xhdpi images by default, if no sw600dp-hdpi folder is defined?

Comment: no if it is nexus-7 it takes from hdpi if there is no sw600dp-hdpi folder. i checked